# Multiple match statements in a Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggling to detect various patterns in a graph database. At the moment I'd like to combine various MATCH statements in one query. I have a test dataset which records, among other things, the Church in which people married. It was possible (we're talking about the early modern Dutch Republic here) that a couple married in the Catholic Church and in the Dutch Reformed Church. I therefore want to create a query which retrieves the names of these people.

Slightly simplified, the building blocks of the graphs consists of three types of nodes: person, event, church. The event node has another label 'marriage', whereas the church node has another label 'Roman Catholic Church' or 'Dutch Reformed Church'. So for example: John Doe's marriage in the Catholic Church exists in this form:

```
(p:Person {name: "John Doe"})-[:MARRIED_AT]->(event:marriage)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
```

Some person nodes have various marriages to various 
Churches associated to them. How retrieve the couples that married in the Catholic Church and Dutch Reformed Church? I created this query, but although it should yield results, it doesn't:

```
Match (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]->(event)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(ch:church:Roman_Catholic_Church), (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]->(event)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(ch:church:Reformed_Church) Return p.name
```

I don't get any error messages, but the query doesn't yield any results (whereas I've checked that my dataset does include people who had their marriage solemnized in two Churches). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are reusing variable that's why you are not getting result, try below query

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]->(:marriage)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(rcc:church:Roman_Catholic_Church),
(p)-[:MARRIED_AT]->(:marriage)-[:TOOK_PLACE_IN]->(rc:church:Reformed_Church) 
RETURN DISTINCT p.name
```

Comment: To add a bit more context, when you reuse a variable in a query (and it hasn't lost scope due to not being included in a WITH clause between usages) then it's referring to the exact same entity. In your previous attempts, by using the same `event` and `ch` variables, you were instructing Cypher to look for patterns where the two events were the same event, and the two churches were the same church.

Comment: Many thanks for the updated query and the extra explanation, which is really helpful. I'm new to all of this and I find that while there's a fair bit of documentation, it either contains really simple or rather difficult queries. The middle ground is a bit missing, or so it seems to me! I tried the query though, and I still don't get any results! :(